# How to run a docker command in Nodejs image

Tags: node.js, docker

I wrote a node app, he can build and push docker image, but I hope to run him as a Docker container.

I can use the following method to run the docker command in the container, but this cannot be running the Node App.

```sh
docker run -i --rm  --privileged docker:dind sh
```

Comment: Take a look at the Docker-API. There is a SDK for Node: 
https://github.com/apocas/dockerode

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer:

```
FROM node

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
       ca-certificates curl gnupg2 \
       software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
       $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
RUN apt-get install -y docker-compose

CMD ["node", "-v"]
```